# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de una columna declarando una variable en SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Estoy creando el nombre de una columna, pero quiero cambiar esa columna (hacerla dinámica) declarando la variable y concatenando el campo para que se pueda mostrar, pero me arroja un error.

```
DECLARE @Fecha1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Fecha2 VARCHAR(50)

SET @Fecha1 = '01 jul'
SET @Fecha2 = '01 ago'

SELECT Periodo AS Fecha + @Fecha1, Mes AS Mes + @Fecha2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra un error de sintaxis, pero la idea es que al cambiar la fecha, el nombre de la columna se cambie igual para no tener que estar cambiando (Como se muestra en la imagen) todos los campos manualmente. Alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

Comment: Lo que pides requiere de código dinámico. Es posible hacerlo en SQL, pero sería mejor si lo haces en el front-end.

Comment: @LuisCazares por el momento solo se requiere en SQL Server, si me puedes apoyar en dónde puedo encontrar información sobre el código dinámico que mencionas, te lo agradecería

Comment: Al codigo de muestra le hace falta la clausula `FROM`. ¿Cual es el nombre de la tabla que contiene las columnas `Periodo` y `Mes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un ejemplo:

```
Create table fechas (Periodo int, Mes varchar(20));

GO
Insert into FECHAS (periodo, mes)
values
(1,'Marzo'),
(2,'abril');
go
```

Para la tabla fechas, lo que propones.

```
DECLARE @Fecha1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Fecha2 VARCHAR(50)

SET @Fecha1 = '01 jul'
SET @Fecha2 = '01 ago'

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000);
Set @SQL = N'SELECT Periodo AS [Fecha' + @Fecha1 +N'], Mes AS [Mes' + @Fecha2 
+ N'] FROM FECHAS;'

EXEC sp_executeSql @sql;
```

[image: Result]

Hay que tener en cuenta, que el código dinámico puede tener su peligro de inyección sql. Además de ser complicado de hacer, y sobre todo con los apóstrofes, porque hay que duplicarlos.

Además es conveniente utilizar parametros para prevenir lo anterior, con el procedimiento sp_excuteSql, que te puede ayudar a prevenirlo.

[Sql dinámico](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/03/sql-dinamico-como-se-hace/)